# Request to rename tag [TVM] to [AWS-TVM] and create [Apache-TVM]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

On SO I can see few questions with the [tvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tvm) tag, but some of them are related to AWS-TVM, which is AWS Token Vending Machine. Other questions are related to software Apache TVM (https://tvm.apache.org/) which is deep learning model compiler. Community of Apache TVM suggest to ask questions on their forum (https://discuss.tvm.apache.org/), but I can see that few people didn't read this recommendation, and posted questions on SO.

Comment: Whether of not a community suggests that users post on their own site or not is irrelevant. [so] strives to be a community of knowledge, and that can be for anything that is on-topic for the site; regardless of if there are other communities or not.

Comment: Also, there is already a [[tag:apache-tvm]] tag. Seems like that [[tag:tvm]] just need disambiguating.